# Android Force Stop Button Not Working Samsung Captivate (A Galaxy S)

Tags: applications, force-close

Settings -> Manage Applications -> Third Party App -> Force Stop is not working.  On clicking, the Force Stop Button does not change.  No Messages either. I can however uninstall the app.  What could be wrong?   This is with a Samsung Captivate on AT&T. Thanks

Comment: What app?  Or is it all of them?

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33801/12442 for a discussion of when the **Force stop** button is enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 3):

The Force Stop button is only applicable to apps which are currently actually running. In general, Android apps will stay in an idle state on the assumption that you might want to switch back to them soon, but the OS will kill apps you haven't used for a while as it gets short on memory. Some apps also have an actual "exit" option, of course.

So, are you sure the app you're trying to Force Stop is actually running? In your applications settings, there should be a "Running" tab, which should show all of the apps currently running on your device. Alternatively there are apps in the Market that can show you what's currently going on on your device. I use "[OS Monitor](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&feature=search_result)" but I'm sure there are others.