# Persistent download icon in One S pull down menu - even with download over days ago. How to remove?

Tags: htc-one-s, download-manager

In the pull down menu of my HTC One S, there is this persistent download icon, it's just stuck there even though download completed days ago. It came when I was doing some app downloads and has refused to go away even after downloads are over.

On the top icon row of the phone, the animated download icon also shows, has been showing for days, even with no downloads.

Rebooting does not get rid of the icons. Does anyone know how to get rid of these? Your help is appreciated.

The screenshots below show the icons - icons of concern are circled in black:

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try [force stopping](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33801/what-force-stop-button-means) the Play Store application from the settings menu and see if that removes it. Facebook photo upload often gets stuck in my notification bar and force stopping removes that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

It was eventually fixed by stopping the Downloads app in  Settings - App - All. I did a Force Stop on the Downloads app, and then rebooted and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was eventually fixed by stopping the Downloads app in  Settings - App - All. I did a Force Stop on the Downloads app, and then rebooted and it was fine.

- Go to Settings - App - All
- go to the 'Downloads' app
- click 'Force Stop'
- Clear cache if button is highlighted, other wise leave it
- Reboot device