# Do Apps restart after phone restart once "Force Stop" is enabled for them?

Tags: reboot, force-close

Building the question on this [What does the “Force stop” button mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33801/what-does-the-force-stop-button-mean) , If I restart the phone , do these Background Apps get started even when ForceStop is enabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Force stop** is a one-off action, not a thing you enable or disable. Force-stopping an app doesn't prevent it restarting any time it would normally start: when you launch it from the apps menu, or through a share action, or automatically via an alarm, broadcast, or on start-up.

The question you link to talks about whether the button is clickable (*enabled*) or greyed-out (*disabled*). That's to say, it's about under what circumstances the **Force stop** button is available for you to click. Force-stopping an app just stops it once, when you click the button. The only long-term effect it has is that force-stopping an app might (in rare cases) corrupt its settings files, making it behave unpredictably in future.