# How do I log off from WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm trying to exit WhatsApp, but it seems that there is no "Log Off" button. Currently, when I want to exit, I turn off my Wi-Fi/cellular data.

How do I log off from WhatsApp?

Comment: This is not possible. Whatsapp is designed to stay online. You may want to use a Firewall or an app which drain the permissions while you dont want to be connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some experiments i think best way is use <kbd>Force stop</kbd> button in Application manager
go to `Setting > Application manager > WhatsApp` and tap <kbd>Force stop</kbd> button

As say [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33803/73129):

> Android do not kill the apps totally when you exit from it, this button is for close completely the app and remove it from the stack (apps running), also this button free the memory used by the app

so Thanks to User [pacoespinoza](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/6771/pacoespinoza)  this is what i want to do!

Comment: The services will still run and the app will be back in no time I'm afraid.

Comment: @RossC you can try it like me and see result! don't afraid

Comment: I tried it on 4 devices, same each time, services run even after activity stack is closed, app is back open.

Comment: @RossC i try it in galaxy s3 and galaxy grand and work well what is yor device??

Comment: S4,s5 htc one m8, nexus 5

Comment: @RossC if you look at 'running' tab in Application manager and tap on whatsapp you can see process and service of whatsapp [see Image](http://i.imgur.com/BDrb6Fm.png) (name is MessageService) and each service have button stop that you can stop background services

Comment: :O  Wow, I completely and utterly forgot that option under 'running'. Wow. Yep, you're completely right, I was just going to Whatsapp under 'Downloaded' in the app manager. I don't know what I was thinking. Cheers for clarifying. I wouldn't have remembered that at all. It's crazy what you forget! A very delayed +1

Answer (score 1):

Settings>apps>WhatsApp and press clear data. You might want to first backup your messages in WhatsApp settings. This resets WhatsApp to like when you first downloaded it before logging in. Alternatively, you can go to settings>apps>WhatsApp and turn off notifications for WhatsApp if it gives you the option. If it doesn't, it means your version of android doesn't support turning off notifications. You can also go to a WhatsApp chat, press menu, and mute conversation for an amount of time.

Comment: clear data?? i wont clear my whatsapp data i want shutdown it!

Comment: It is a valid work around to be fair. Considering you can't directly log off. A rooted user could just freeze the app, or clear and restore data with one or two clicks so this would be particularly easy to do.

Answer (score -2):

Go to applications and clear data

Comment: Actually, this would work because opening WhatsApp will require you to log in again. You might want to ensure your daily WhatsApp backups are in order and trigger it once manually for good measure before doing this though. Wiping WhatsApp app data will not remove the WhatsApp backups.

Comment: as you say yourself , it just clear data not exit app