# Restarting Google Play Services after forced-stopping it

Tags: google-play-services

I didn't know I would need Google Play Service if I didn't play games, so I forced stop it.

Any way of getting back, possibly without doing a factory reset?

Comment: See  [What does the "Force stop" button mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33801/what-does-the-force-stop-button-mean)

Answer (score 0):

If you only forced stop it, then you don't have to worry. It will start itself when opening Google Play Store. Check the running apps for Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if you Force Stop Google Play Services, it will start again when you open Play Store. However, the Play Services app may misbehave when Force Stopped - when re-opening, (on my Chrome OS) it installs gaming, book, video apps that I never use and have uninstalled at least 10 times. But this is a minor issue and aside from that, you should have no problem re-starting Play Services.