# Recent apps list repopulates on Samsung S7 (Nougat)

Tags: samsung, bugs, samsung-galaxy-s7, 7.1-nougat, recents-screen

I've got a question for the experts here. I've recently begun clearing my recently used apps list before bed. When I awake, I check it to find that a bunch of apps that have popped into the list - some apps that I haven't used recently at all (if ever?), let alone obviously not used during the night. This is happening even after clearing the apps and a reboot of the phone.

Any idea why this could be happening? Is this a feature? A bug? A hack?

ps - this happens during the day as well. After a period of inactivity in my pocket, there might be a few new random apps in the list. They range from config apps to messages to anything really. I have PIN lock enabled and lock-screen notifications disabled.

Comment: [Swiping doesn't kill the app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19987/131553) - since I don't have Nougat can't confirm if the behaviour holds

Comment: Also see this - https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132929/131553